# ERROR: relation "foo.event" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to setup Spring boot RESTful API with Hibernate, JPA and PostgreSQL 9.5 into a Linux server. I'm not very experienced with any of the technologies, but got the task anyway. I'm getting following errors when running jar on server:

```
2018-02-03 14:48:09.376  WARN 22357 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
2018-02-03 14:48:09.894  INFO 22357 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into foo.event (description, end_date, end_time, name, start_date, start_time, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-02-03 14:48:10.559  WARN 22357 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2018-02-03 14:48:10.560 ERROR 22357 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "foo.event" does not exist
  Position: 13
2018-02-03 14:48:10.562  INFO 22357 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-02-03 14:48:10.565 ERROR 22357 --- [           main] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
2018-02-03 14:48:10.570  WARN 22357 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
2018-02-03 14:48:10.571  INFO 22357 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-03 14:48:10.587  INFO 22357 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-02-03 14:48:10.615  INFO 22357 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-03 14:48:10.631 ERROR 22357 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at partio.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [tosu-backend-0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [tosu-backend-0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [tosu-backend-0.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [tosu-backend-0.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at partio.service.EventService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c9b3c58.add(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at partio.controller.EventController.construct(EventController.java:24) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3513) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "foo.event" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:135) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar!/:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar!/:5.2.12.Final]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Event.java:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "event", schema="foo")
public class Event extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private LocalTime startTime;
    private LocalTime endTime;  
    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String description;
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foodb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=foobar
server.port=3001

spring.jpa.generate-dll=true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto = create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
        id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.11'
        id 'java'
}
lombok {
        version = "1.16.20"
        sha256 = ""
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}



apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'


jar {
    baseName = 'backend'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.Application'
    }
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
mainClassName='main.Application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '1.5.10.REL$
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1$
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.12.Final")
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.2.12.Final'
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.1'
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1212.jre7")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

}
```

I've tried almost everything I've been able to find relating to issue, and I'm quite sure some of the fixes I've done have done even more harm.

So for some reason JPA/Hibernate isn't creating table event. And I have no idea why.

Edit: It works fine when I make table to database myself, but that isn't the idea of Hibernate, right?

Comment: did you check your database, do you have schema named foo

Comment: Yes, I made it earlier, but of course I'm not sure what it should contain.

Comment: And you are able to execute an SQL statement with that user against PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, tried with create table, insert and select and everything worked ok.

Comment: The error clearly says there is no table named `event` in schema `foo`. Make sure you got the schema and table names right.

Comment: Hibernate and/or JPA should make that table for me, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured that out long time ago obviously, but finally remembered to put it here. So I finally used own class for settings instead of application.properties. Added all the settings into HashMap and injected that into StandardServiceRegistryBuilder which was injected into MetadataSources. Then I had to annotate all the classes into MetadataSources instance and make a new instance of SchemaExport using metadatasources as parameter.

```
public class PostgreSQLDatabaseGenerator {

public void generate() {
    Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
    settings.put("spring.datasource.driverClassName", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    settings.put("spring.jpa.database-platform", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foodb?useSSL=false");
    settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", "postgres");
    settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", "bar");
    settings.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    settings.put("show_sql", "true");
    settings.put("server.port", "3001");
    settings.put("server.ssl.key-store-type", "PKCS12");
    settings.put("server.ssl.key-store", "/var/www/certificate.p12");
    settings.put("server.ssl.key-store-password", "foo");
    settings.put("server.ssl.key-password", "bar");

    MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(settings)
                    .build());
    metadata.addAnnotatedClass(Foo.class);
    metadata.addAnnotatedClass(Bar.class);
   SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(
            (MetadataImplementor) metadata.buildMetadata()
    );
    schemaExport.setHaltOnError(true);
    schemaExport.setFormat(true);`enter code here`
    schemaExport.setDelimiter(";");
    schemaExport.setOutputFile("db-schema.sql");
    schemaExport.execute(true, true, false, true);
}
```

}`